Vacuum entanglement: between what and what, exactly?
I sometimes read that the entanglement of the vacuum state of a field -- maximal and ubiquitous -- is an inescapable axiom of QFT. In articles often oriented towards AQFT, but also in this intervention by Susskind (from 32mn30: https://www.cornell.edu/video/leonar...3-entanglement).
But what exactly is this entanglement between?
As far as the video is concerned, there would be entanglement between separate regions of the same field, even if this separation were a space-like interval. These regions (Susskind calls them “cells”) would then constitute non-separable subsystems. As a result, everything contained in any one region, by which I mean all the field variables it contains, are entangled with variables contained in other regions.
But can we then infer, from this entanglement (between cells, and consequently between the variables or degrees of freedom of these cells), the one suggested by Susskind, namely, an entanglement between vacuum fluctuations, or virtual particles?
The answer seems to me to be yes, but I'd like to be quite sure.
Especially since, in a recent article, Susskind writes: “In the vacuum of a quantum field theory, the quantum fields in disjoint regions of space are entangled. One way to picture this is that virtual pairs of entangled particles are constantly appearing for short times”.
Well, it's one thing to derive from the entanglement of regions the entanglement of their (in this case virtual) fluctuations, but to consider that one is a possible translation (“picture”) of the other is to take it one step further, it seems to me.

Do they give a precise definition of entanglement in this context?

Susskind's article doesn't offer a formal definition (it's presupposed), but precise elements that allow us to reconstitute one “with our hands”, and quite orthodox: a set of non-local correlations that can be used as a “fungible resource”, useful for certain communication tasks (teleportation) and kept only under certain conditions.

You don't state where you have read about vacuum state entanglement and only provide a video as a source. There is an statement about the entanglement of the vacuum state in "Quantum Information and Relativity Theory" by Peres and Terno:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0212023

It asserts that there are local operators $Q \in A(O)$ which, applied to the vacuum, produce a state which is arbitrarily close to any arbitrary $|\gamma\rangle$ (the vacuum state can be replaced by any state of finite energy). Thus in principle any entangled state can be arbitrarily closely approximated by suitable local operations on any other state.
The theorem reveals a surprising amount of entanglement that is present in the vacuum state $|\Omega\rangle$. The corollary below shows that if a local operator is used to model a detector, that detector must have “dark counts”: it has a finite probability to “click” in a vacuum.

So the entanglement occurs between the states of the field at two different locations and has implications that include dark counts of detectors.

Well, there's Susskind's article, "Copenhagen vs Everett, Teleportation, and ER=EPR", or Yet more ado about Nothing by SJ Summers. Didn't thought that such a video from Susskind himself would be considered as a poor material.

But thank you for your ressource !!

Written material is easier to search and quote.

That is the very well known Reeh-Schlieder theorem and not a result by Peres and Terno, (and it is acknowledged in the paper).

alanf ; If it's true that vacuum fluctuations, including virtual particles, are manifestations of the quantum field's degrees of freedom ; thus, the entanglement of regions of the field implies the entanglement of their fluctuations, including virtual particles. Or is it precisely untrue ? I'm tryinf to understand Susskind's assertion

Vacuum fluctuation is a term that describes the fact that in the vacuum state a particle detector can absorb a quantum of energy. As stated in the paper linked the detector can go in a vacuum state as a result of vacuum entanglement so the answer is yes.

Thank you very much! I had already read about entanglement between modes of the field (in the vacuum state), or between its degrees of freedom -- but nothing about the entanglement of vacuum fluctuations, and the implication wasn't crystal clear to me. Clearly, entanglement is ubiquitous.
